# Why does Chat have so many negative user IDs?

Tags: support, chat

In Chat, there are users with negative user IDs:

-1: Community
-2: Feeds
                                                   ...
-17: SO Migrations

These users do not exist on the main SO site.

Then why are they on Chat?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Those are all system users**

There is a very old (from 2010) MSE post asking about the same thing:

[System Users for Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59796/786798)

Basically, those are identical to the Feeds user, but can be created by moderators and customized with a name and a gravatar.

Here is a small list of "negative" users with prominent identities.

Stack Exchange Chat Server:

| UserId | User | About/Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-2` | [Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2) | I'm not just a bot: sometimes I post feed items, sometimes I post room status changes, sometimes I dream about electric unic♦rns. |
| `-9` and `-10` (meta) | [Unix and Linux](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-9) | Feed for posts on the Unix and Linux SE |
| `-21` | [Wheatley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-21) | They told me I would die if I posted messages! They lied about everything! |
| `-22` | [Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-22) | Some feeds are unlike others. |
| `-23` | [Lazers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-23) | RIP Lazers 1.0 Light Amplification from Zeta Epsilon Radiation from Space. Looks like those boring ol' LASER stuff from the 20th century, but is about 20 times more awesome and powerful. |
| `-54` and `-55` | [Aspen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-55) and [Mr. Tiller](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-54) | Hi, I'm part of the gardening duo - Aspen & Tiller. I'll be notifying you of new gardening questions as they arrive |
| `-357` and `-428` | - | 2 strange system users that are either XSS vulnerability testing or hacking attempts |
| `-638` | [Marvin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-638) | I didn’t ask to be made: no one consulted me or considered my feelings in the matter. I don’t think it even occurred to them that I might have feelings. Pronouns: I’m just a bot. |
| `-678` to `-692` | - | Various bots (worth mentioning since those are sequential) |
| `-727` | [Squidge the Octopus](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-727) |  |
| `-781` | [Smoke Detector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-781) | Crush. Kill. Destroy. (Spam that is) |
| `-1165` | [Remove courses tag and tell Catija: We told you so](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-1165) | [Should [courses] be a synonym of [coursework]?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4908) |

StackOverflow Chat Server:

| UserId | User | About/Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-1` | [Community](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) | - |
| `-2` | [Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2) | - |
| `-3` | [Qt](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-3/qt) | [What is the system user Qt for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123577/786798) |
| `-13` | [Burnination Feed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-13) | - |
| `-15` | [Featured on Meta](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-15) | - |
| `-16` | [New Posts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-16) | - |

Meta Stack Exchange Chat Server (turns out, Planet Express moved there)

| UserId | User | About/Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-59` | [Hermes Conrad](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-59) | Bureaucracy, mon |
| `-61` | [Scruffy](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-61) | Scruffy believes in this company. |
| `-81` | [Malfunctioning Eddie](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-81) | - |
| `-113` | [Hermes](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-113) | I may also know me as Mercury, if you're more into Roman mythology than into Greek mythology. Either way, I'm an emissary and messenger of the gods. I'm not that guy from Futurama. |
| `-186` | [Mom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-186) | I'm a bot! I post stuff that needs attention from the Trello CoGro Backlog Board. The name is a reference to Futurama, not a problematic trope |

Comment: Why is Marvin not -42?

Comment: @user4581301 heh, who knows - I tried to find anything witty or at least interesting at id `-42` on all three chat servers, but it appears that no Douglas fan worked on chat :)

Answer (score 4):

#### They're system bots, not real users

They only exist within the chat system.  They have negative user IDs to not conflict with the user IDs of actual users.

You are mistaken on one minor point, though: the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user does exist on the main site, because that bot also takes actions there.  They've even posted [a few Meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)!